# spring boot 2.1.3 onward throws circular reference

Tags: spring, spring-boot

```
public abstract class CommonBillService implements BillService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("onlineProfitServiceImpl")
    private ProfitService profitService;
....
}

@Service
public class OnlineProfitServiceImpl implements ProfitService { 

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("aBillServiceImpl")
    private BillService aBillService;
}

@Service
public class ABillServiceImpl extends CommonBillService implements Move {
....//inject other services or dao here with @Autowired,
//there is no OnlineProfitService here explicitly, but its parent CommonBillService inject OnlineProfitService by autowired
}
```

this code works under spring boot `2.1.2`, but failed with `circular reference` under `2.1.3`:

```
Error creating bean with name 'aBillServiceImpl': 
Bean with name 'aBillServiceImpl' has been injected into other beans [onlineProfitServiceImpl] 
in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. 
This means that said other beans do not use the final version of the bean.
```

but my code has no constructor injection, i just use `@Autowired` to inject, so it is not possible to  throw `circular reference`, right?

Comment: Could you please add `aBillServiceImpl` bean definition? Also, if that initialized class object is not here, put the class declaration as well.

Comment: That's clearly a circular reference. Spring Boot 2.1.3 might have a change to detect such and throw error.

Comment: You can fix it by analyzing and extracting the code into a new Service/Component

Comment: @SachithDickwella `aBillServiceImpl` inject other service or dao by `@Autowired`, but there is no `OnlineProfitServiceImpl` in it explicitly, but in its parent class `CommonBillService`

Comment: @gtiwari333 yes, i can fix it just like you said. spring can handle circular reference if the injection is not constructor inject without throwing error, right? but my case has no constructor injection and it throws circular reference error, so does it means spring also cannot circular reference of setter/autowired injection from 2.1.3?

Comment: `spring can handle circular reference if the injection is not constructor inject without throwing error` I don't think this is true.